# consulta sql oracle update con select

Tags: sql, oracle

ya estoy  uy cerca pero aun no resuelvo esto

```
UPDATE TABLA_USUARIOS
SET
    SALDO = SALDO + (
        SELECT
            T.VALOR
        FROM
                 TABLA_TRANSACCIONES T
            JOIN TABLA_USUARIOS U ON U.ID = T.ID
        WHERE
                T.ESTADO_TRANSA = 'aceptado'
            AND ( UPPER(T.DESAFIO) = UPPER(:EQUIPO) )
            AND T.POSITIVO = U.TELEFONO
    ) 
WHERE  ID = (SELECT
            T.ID
        FROM
                 TABLA_TRANSACCIONES T
            JOIN TABLA_USUARIOS U ON U.ID = T.ID
        WHERE
                T.ESTADO_TRANSA = 'aceptado'
            AND ( UPPER(T.DESAFIO) = UPPER(:EQUIPO) )
            AND T.POSITIVO = U.TELEFONO)
```

hasta aqui  la subconsulta del set me da el VALOR ok, la subconsulta del where me da el ID  ok y modifica bien el SALDO.

el problema es cuando hay mas de un registro en esos SELECT. ahi ya aparecen varios registros que contienen dif valores y diferentes id por lo que me da

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿`ON U.ID = T.ID`? ¿Es esto voluntario? Un usuario y una transacción son dos cosas diferentes. Quizás hay una ID del usuario en la tabla transacción que necesitas usar en vez. Algo como `ON U.ID = T.ID_USARIO`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Azael Lon creo que lo que tienes mal es que en el set le estas poniendo el nombre de las columnas que sobrescritas cuando no deberías de hacerlo.

```
UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios.Saldo =  ((usuarios.VALOR * 2) + usuarios.SALDO) from (SELECT  U.ID,

            U.SALDO,

            U.ESTADO,

            T.VALOR,

            T.ESTADO_TRANSA,

            T.DESAFIO,

            T.ID_T,

            T.POSITIVO

        FROM TABLA_USUARIOS U  

        JOIN TABLA_TRANSACCIONES T ON U.ID = T.ID

        WHERE T.ESTADO_TRANSA= 'aceptado' AND (UPPER(T.DESAFIO) = UPPER(:ganador)) AND 
T.POSITIVO = U.TELEFONO) usuarios
```

He modificado la respuesta @Azael espero que así te sirva, yo he hecho una prueba con dos tablas y me ha funcionado de esta manera. Espero que con tus campos que funcione.

Comment: me da error ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table.

Comment: He modificato la respuesta haner si asi te funciona ahora he cambiado por completo la consulta pero la he probado y me ha funcionado.

Comment: gracias jordi me da este >> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. he intentado por muchas formas y no me da. borre los registros y deje solo dos uno de los cuales cumple las condiciones para actualizarse y no me funciona.